How to add Qutip to Spyder?
I installed the Qutip package on the Windows terminal, and I've seen it works perfectly when I use it on jupyter notebooks from the Windows terminal. Instead, when I've tried to use it in Spyder, instead, I have received an error message with "ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'qutip'".
I have tried to follow the instructions given on the Spyder website (https://docs.spyder-ide.org/5/faq.html#using-existing-environment). First attempt was going on the Anaconda prompt and putting:
conda install conda-forge::qutip
The installation worked, but Spyder still gave the same error. Then I tried another procedure given in their website:
conda create -n my-env -c conda-forge spyder-kernels qutip
Again, in installed a series of packages, but in Spyder it continued not to work.

Are Spyder and Jupyter staring from the same environment?

No, they're not. I just don't know how to import qutip to the Spyder environment.

I think it is not exactly a question about QuTip but about Spyder usage. You need to set Spyder environment to be the same that you have installed QuTiP.
To do so, first use

conda env list

to find the path of QuTiP env. Then on Tools > Preferences > Python interpreter define the interpteter to the paht of the desired env, and restart the Kernel.
More info at: https://docs.spyder-ide.org/current/faq.html#using-spyder

Hi, sorry for being such a noob, but I've typed conda env list on the Windows terminal and I've received the following message  "The term 'conda' is not recognized as the name of a cmdlet, function, script file, or operable program. Check
the spelling of the name, or if a path was included, verify that the path is correct and try again.". Also when I've typed "conda env list" on the Anaconda prompt I've received a similar message. I don't know if I had to type that command in a specific folder or what.

Don't worry about the question, we're all noobs in some matter. Windows cmd doesn't recognizes anaconda. So the Anaconda prompt should be the place to do all python related commands. If it is not working the simple way is to just run ´conda env list´ directly at the spyder console. (The one with the ´In [1]:´ usually at the bottom right panel). You cold also simply skip the list part and just go to setting the Python Interpreter. Since you probably don't have that many envs it should be simple to see which one it the qutip one. Send any messages if you still have trouble. Nice learning
